# Moving files to sub-folders

Tags: power-automate, workflow-activity

How can I move files to various sub-folders using Power Automate?

For example:

move approved Guest Policy to Policies/Guest Policy (sub-folder)

move approved Checkout Policy to Policies/Checkout Policy (sub-folder)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Power Automate has a copy file task which you could use to move a file to a specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Copy File](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/file#copy) action in Power Automate to achieve this.

[image]